# using java to draw the shortest line and the longest line with different colors

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel

I am trying to draw the shortest line that I draw with a different color (green) and the longest line that I draw with another (white). How can I do that? Should I use if else statement?

And even if I do that I can make it nearest to 0 to print a different color I guess but that makes no sense when the line is actually zero.

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;

   public class DotsPanel extends JPanel
  {
   private final int SIZE = 6;  // radius of each dot
    private int selectedCircle = -1;
   private int length = 0;
   private int i = 0;
   private int totalDistance = 0;

   private ArrayList<PointCount> pointList;

    public DotsPanel()
   {
      pointList = new ArrayList<PointCount>();
  addMouseListener (new DotsListener());
  addMouseMotionListener (new DotsListener());
  setBackground(Color.black);
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  { 
      super.paintComponent(g);
      int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      int minIndex = -1;  
      int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      int maxIndex = -1;  

  for(i=0; i < pointList.size()-1;i++){      
    length = (int)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pointList.get(i).x -  pointList.get(i+1).x, 2)+
                            Math.pow(pointList.get(i).y - pointList.get(i+1).y, 2));

    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.drawString("" + length,(pointList.get(i).x+pointList.get(i+1).x)/2, (pointList.get(i).y+pointList.get(i+1).y)/2);

}
 totalDistance += length; 

 for(i=0; i < pointList.size()-1;i++){
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawLine(pointList.get(i).x,
               pointList.get(i).y,
               pointList.get(i+1).x,
               pointList.get(i+1).y);

    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillOval(pointList.get(i+1).x-SIZE,
               pointList.get(i+1).y-SIZE, 
               SIZE*2, 
               SIZE*2);

    // --- Displays counts
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawString("" + pointList.get(i+1).getCount(), 
                 pointList.get(i+1).x,
                 pointList.get(i+1).y);      
  }
 for(i=0; i < pointList.size()-2; i++) {
 int distance = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pointList.get(i).x -  pointList.get(i+1).x, 2)+
                              Math.pow(pointList.get(i).y - pointList.get(i+1).y, 2));

   if(distance > max) {
       max = distance;
       maxIndex = i;        
       g.setColor(Color.red);
       g.drawLine(pointList.get(i).x,
               pointList.get(i).y,
               pointList.get(i+1).x,
               pointList.get(i+1).y);
   }

   if(distance < min) {
       min = distance;
       minIndex = i;
       g.setColor(Color.green);
       g.drawLine(pointList.get(i).x,
               pointList.get(i).y,
               pointList.get(i+1).x,
               pointList.get(i+1).y);
   }
 }


    g.setColor(Color.white); 
    g.drawString("Count: " + pointList.size(), 5, 15);
    g.drawString("Total Distance: " + totalDistance, 5, 30);

   }

     private class DotsListener implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener
   {
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
     {
       boolean spotSelected = false;


    int count = 0;
    while(count < pointList.size() && !spotSelected) {
      Point current = pointList.get(count).getPoint();

      if(getDistance(event.getPoint(), current) <= SIZE) {
        // --- Spot/circle selected or clicked on again
        pointList.get(count).addCount();
        spotSelected = false;
      }

      count++;
    }

    // --- Checks whether a new object needs to be created
    if(!spotSelected) {  // spotSelected == false
      pointList.add(new PointCount(event.getPoint()));
    }

    repaint();
  }

  //--------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Provide empty definitions for unused event methods.
  //--------------------------------------------------------------
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){} 
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}    
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
     }

      private int getDistance(Point p1, Point p2) {
      return (int)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2)+
                       Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
    }


 }
```

Comment: I imagine you would need to know more information, for example, you would need to maintain each point in a `List` or array or generate a `Line` class which maintained that information, which could then calculate the line length. You could then sort the list which would make it easier to determine which was the shortest and longest, but you could also calculate that when `mouseReleased` is called

Comment: Yes then after i get the length what should i do

Comment: That would depend on "how" you're maintaining the information AND if you want to display all the other lines you've drawen

Comment: Ok g.drawline(my cordinates)  and making them appear all the time. After that

Comment: Making int lines with Point cordinates pt1 pt2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this, this, for example, creates a simple `Line` class which is `Comparable` and which can calculate its own length.  These are stored in a `List` which is sorted, so the shortest is first and the longest is last, making it a simple thing to pick them out of the `List` and paint them

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Line> lines;

        public TestPane() {
            lines = new ArrayList<Line>(25);
            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                private Line currentLine;

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    currentLine = new Line(e.getPoint());
                    Collections.sort(lines);
                    lines.add(currentLine);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    currentLine = null;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    currentLine.to(e.getPoint());
                    Collections.sort(lines);
                    repaint();
                }

            };
            addMouseListener(ma);
            addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (!lines.isEmpty()) {
                Line shortest = lines.get(0);
                Line longest = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
                if (lines.size() > 2) {
                    lines.subList(1, lines.size() - 2);
                    for (Line line : lines) {
                        g2d.draw(line.getShape());
                    }
                }

                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.draw(shortest.getShape());
                if (!longest.equals(shortest)) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g2d.draw(longest.getShape());
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class Line implements Comparable<Line> {

        private Point p1;
        private Point p2;

        public Line(Point p1) {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p1;
        }

        public Line to(Point p) {
            p2 = p;
            return this;
        }

        public double getLength() {
            return Math.sqrt(((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x)) + ((p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)));
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Line o) {
            return (int) (getLength() - o.getLength());
        }

        public Line2D getShape() {
            return new Line2D.Double(p1, p2);
        }

    }

}
```

**Update**

You need to determine the shortest/longest lines BEFORE you paint them, it's too late once you've started.

One way is to calculate the longest and shortest lengths when you add a new point, for example...

```
private class DotsListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        boolean spotSelected = false;

        int count = 0;
        while (count < pointList.size() && !spotSelected) {
            Point current = pointList.get(count).getPoint();

            if (getDistance(event.getPoint(), current) <= SIZE) {
                // --- Spot/circle selected or clicked on again
                pointList.get(count).addCount();
                spotSelected = false;
            }

            count++;
        }

        // --- Checks whether a new object needs to be created
        if (!spotSelected) {  // spotSelected == false
            pointList.add(new PointCount(event.getPoint()));

            if (pointList.size() > 1) {
                // Here, you now need to determine if the distance between the this and
                // the previous point is the shortest or longest
                longest = Math.max(longest, getDistance(pointList.get(pointList.size() - 1), pointList.get(pointList.size() - 2)));
                shortest = Math.min(shortest, getDistance(pointList.get(pointList.size() - 1), pointList.get(pointList.size() - 2)));
            }
        }

        repaint();
    }
```

Then when you paint the lines, you'd just calculate the distance between each point and determine if they are the same length of as the longest or shortest lines...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minIndex = -1;
    int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxIndex = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < pointList.size() - 1; i++) {
        length = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pointList.get(i).x - pointList.get(i + 1).x, 2)
                + Math.pow(pointList.get(i).y - pointList.get(i + 1).y, 2));

        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.drawString("" + length, (pointList.get(i).x + pointList.get(i + 1).x) / 2, (pointList.get(i).y + pointList.get(i + 1).y) / 2);

    }
    totalDistance += length;

    for (i = 0; i < pointList.size() - 1; i++) {

        Point from = pointList.get(i);
        Point to = pointList.get(i + 1);

        int distance = getDistance(from, to);
        if (distance == longest) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else if (distance == shortest) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        //...
```

Comment: yes this is correct but do you know how can i do it without 2d thanks for replying :)

Comment: Graphics.drawLine?

Comment: if you can help me out

Comment: Replace g2d.draw with g2d.drawLine. Graphics2D is an extension to Graphics and the paint system guarantees an instance of Graphics2D. With respect, I'm not going to do any more code as I've practically completed your assignment anyway

Comment: I tried but what should i do about the shape   `g2d.draw(shortest.getShape());` i can not draw shape in Graphics.drawline shortest

Comment: Line is made up of two points, you will need to use these to get the individual x/y coordinates for the drawLine method

Comment: yes  i am drawing line like this g.drawLine(pointList.get(i).x,
                   pointList.get(i).y,
                   pointList.get(i+1).x,
                   pointList.get(i+1).y);

Comment: but when i draw a line then another shorter then the one before it paints it green but when i draw one more line smaller then the green line that line is also green which don't revert the other shortest to its default color.

Comment: i am all done with my program just have this small issue

Comment: Have you determined which line is the shortest/longest in your point list? That's kind of the point of using the line class and the list

Comment: using if else statement

Comment: i have changed my code in my question so you can see please help me out

Comment: You need to know before you start drawing which set of points will generate the shortest/longest line, then you can use an if-else statement during the paint loop

Comment: yes i did it with a if else loop thats the only method i know hopefully its right

Comment: stuck with this program from last three days

Comment: The loop you use for rendering the lines will paint multiple lines as shortest and longest, depending on the order of the points, you need to know the min/max length before you start the loop

Comment: how can i do find that

Comment: There's lots of ways, you could run though the list before you paint the lines and calculate the min/max values. When you process a new point, you could calculate the distance between the last point and the new point and maintain the max/min values as instance variables

Comment: i did that i found the distance

Comment: is these anyway you can send me the method

Comment: i am totally irritated with this assignment right now :0

Comment: Not while I'm on the train

Comment: Make `totalDistance` a local variable within `paintComponent`

Comment: that fixed it .the longest line is showing up in different color but not the shortest

Comment: Put some `System.out.println` statements, print out the `shortest` and the `distance` value of each line in the `paintComponent` method and make sure the calculations are correct

Comment: nope not working  . its alright i will just submit it like this i have to study other stuff too